# PHP Regex - Get string between two characters (lat/lng)

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, I have a string containing a lat/lng, such as: `(38.889373, -77.00279599999999)`

I want to extract the first number (the lat), returning `38.889373`. Separately, I want to extract the second number (the lng), returning `-77.00279599999999`.

Regex kicks my ass, every time. Help appreciated!

Comment: no reg ex needed, explode on comma, trim\substring  to remove space\brackets

Comment: Why not explode() and trim()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '(38.889373, -77.00279599999999)';
//  $string = str_replace('(','',$string);
//  $string = str_replace(')','',$string);
$string = str_replace(array(')','('),'',$string);


$string = explode(',',$string);

for($i = 0; $i < count($string); $i++) {
   echo $string[$i];
}
```

Comment: str_replace() will accept an array - better than calling it twice

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks for your help on this, and apologies for taking so long to mark this as "solved". Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of everyone's suggestions I really think that a regex is the simplest way.  I believe we can assume that there will be only the two numbers (latitude and logitude) per string / line.

```
preg_match_all("/[\d.-]+/", $str, $matches);
```

The array of pairs (if there are multiple lat/lon sets) are in `$matches[0]`.  You could then  use `array_chunk($matches[0], 2)`.

Comment: some lat\longs come with N-S and E-W instead of positive\negative